# Open a file selection dialog in a html form just to get a file name, WITHOUT uploading the file

Tags: html, forms, file-upload

I just want to retrieve the name of selected file without physically uploading the file. Using something like

```
<form method="post" action="file-upload-1.htm" name="submit" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="fileField"><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

will upload the file, what I want to avoid. How can prevent the upload to happen ?

Thanks for the answer,

JPS

Answer (score 0):

try using some js...

```
    <form method="post" action="javascript: getName();" name="submit" enctype="multipart/form-data">   
<input id="myId" class="button" name="myFile" type="file"><br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
    function getName() {
        alert(document.getElementById("myId").value);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to submit at all, take out the form and just use an onchange in your file input like...

```
<input id="myId" class="button" name="myFile" type="file" onchange="getName()" >

<script>
    function getName() {
        alert(document.getElementById("myId").value);
    }
</script>
```